# Python - program to print steps

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a program which has to do as follows eg.

```
How many steps? 4
__
  |_
    |_
      |_
________|

How many steps? 1
__
__|
```

using _ and |

So far I've got this as my code (pretty much useless)

```
i = int(input('How many steps? '))
spc = (' ')
s = '' * inp
z = '\n''  ''|''_'
print('__'+z*i+'__'*i)
```

Would I be able to have some help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
n = int(input('How many steps? '))

print("__") # top

for i in range(n-1):
    print("  "*(i+1) + "|" + "_")

print("__" * n + "|") # last step
```

**Note:** This works for *n > 0*.

Comment: That came with an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'